# .htaccess 301 redirect not working correctly. Need to force HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

We would like to force all requests to our website to use the HTTPS protocol. We just want to replace the protocol of the URL, the rest of the URI can stay the same. Everything works when we start browsing through the website from the homepage. When we open any other page that isn't the homepage first (i.e. ourdomain.com/this-is-a-page/) we don't get redirected to use HTTPS. What do I need to change on my htaccess file to accomplish this?

This works (it inserts https): ourdomain.com

This doesn't work: ourdomain.com/this-is-a-page/

Thanks!

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: do you have any other rules or redirects?

Comment: @Gigi - Did you refer to [this](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-https) when writing your rule?

Comment: @JonLin - Yes, I have other rules. I edited the htaccess code above to include all rules.

Comment: @MikeAnthony I did refer to that. The only thing I changed was "RewriteCond %{HTTPS}" so that is was checking for "off" instead of "!on" (not on).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put your redirect rule **before** your routing rule. The rewrite engine loops so the routing rule (which routes stuff to `index.php`) gets executed first, the rewrite engine loops, then the second redirect rule gets applied, which redirects the *wrong thing*. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: That worked. I appreciate the explanation as well. I got an answer _and_ I learned something new about how to apply htaccess rules. Thanks!